# When using jQuery Ajax why is everything done with a POST method? I looked it up and cant really find a definite answer on this

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

```
$.post("post-comments.php", {
    author: "Jeremy",
    message: "new message"
  },
  (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
$.ajax({
  url: "put-comments.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    id: 62,
    author: "Janice",
    message: "new updated message"
  },
  success: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: "delete.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    id: 61
  },
  success: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

Comment: Normally `POST` is used for requests that change something, and `GET` is used for requests that just retrieve something.

Comment: `POST` allows larger parameters. `GET` parameters are put in the URL, so they're limited to the maximmum URL size.

Comment: if you want send some data to server and save over server then you use post. GET method is also used but it is for retriving data from server.

$.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });

Comment: So POST allows for PUT and DELETE params?

Comment: everything *isn't* done with post. your assertion is incorrect and thus the question invalid/unclear.

Answer (score -1):

'
***GET - Requests data from a specified resource***'

'***POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource***

GET is basically used for just getting (retrieving) some data from the server. Note: The GET method may return cached data.

POST can also be used to get some data from the server. However, the POST method NEVER caches data, and is often used to send data along with the request.

GET is designed for getting data from the server. POST (and lesser-known friends PUT and DELETE) are designed for modifying data on the server.

A GET request should never cause data to be removed from an application. If you have a link you can click on with a GET to remove data, then Google spidering your site could click on all your "Delete" links.'

'In your AJAX call, you need to use whatever method your server supports. You should always design your server so that operations that modify data are called by POST/PUT/DELETE. Other comments have links to REST, which generally maps C/R/U/D to "POST or PUT"(Create)/GET(Read)/PUT(Update)/DELETE(Delete).'